# HttpURLConnection sending json object as base64. Why?

Tags: java, json, http, post

I have this code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://httpbin.org/post");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);
String jSonString = JSONUtils.toJSONString(request);
byte[] outputInBytes = jSonString.getBytes();
OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
os.write(outputInBytes);
os.close();
```

What I want with it is to send the `request` object as a JSON. The problem is: the JSON is being sending encoded in Base64 without me want it to. I print the `jSonString` and it's the correct JSON, but when I print the mirrored response from httbin I notice that the JSON was sent Base64 encoded. If I decode it, it's the correct JSON object string, but I don't want it to be sent encoded. Does anyone knows why this is happening?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If you're saying `jSonString` is the correct JSON, nothing in your code would produce base64. The httpbin service must be doing it when returning the response.

Answer (score -1):

It could be the `jSonString.getBytes()` doing the conversion. The API states getBytes() "Encodes this String into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset". So it could vary based on the environment on which this is running.

String also has a `getBytes(Charset charset)` method. I'm not familiar with all the charsets, but perhaps trying `jSonString.getBytes("UTF8")` would work.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what a character set is.